# Laravel Valet + dnsmasq don't work (dnsmasq status error)

Tags: php, macos, laravel, dnsmasq, laravel-valet

I've upgraded to Valet 2 and PHP 7.1.

When I reinstall valet and ran `valet install`, `dnsmasq` didn't start.

```
laravel brew services list
Name                       Status  User Plist
dnsmasq                    error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist
elasticsearch              started wise /Users/wise/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.elasticsearch.plist
...
...
```

`dnsmasq` status is error (red).

When I check ports `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP`, dnsmasq is there:

```
...
dnsmasq   31919         nobody    5u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d5067      0t0    TCP 192.168.0.101:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   31919         nobody    7u  IPv4 0xebbcb007ea2bfc87      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   31919         nobody    9u  IPv6 0xebbcb007e3cdecb7      0t0    TCP [fe80:8::d830:c1ff:fe65:f27d]:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   31919         nobody   11u  IPv6 0xebbcb007dfd20c77      0t0    TCP [fe80:4::3e15:c2ff:fedb:2ae0]:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   31919         nobody   13u  IPv6 0xebbcb007dfd211d7      0t0    TCP [fe80:1::1]:53 (LISTEN)
dnsmasq   31919         nobody   15u  IPv6 0xebbcb007e3cdd737      0t0    TCP [::1]:53 (LISTEN)
nginx     32053           root    6u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d3e77      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     32064           wise    6u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d3e77      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     32065           wise    6u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d3e77      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     32066           wise    6u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d3e77      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx     32067           wise    6u  IPv4 0xebbcb007e91d3e77      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

Even works `ping` to the test laravel app:

```
➜  laravel ping laravel-5.3.dev 
PING laravel-5.3.dev (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.224 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
```

But when I visit the url `laravel-5.3.dev` via the browser, I got `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

dnsmasq doesn't start after restart too (`brew services restart dnsmasq` - even with sudo). Still the same red error status.

Don't you know, where the problem can be?

Thank you.

Jakub